# Hiding Documents Section For Recipient View

Tags: docusignapi

We are using embedded signing to display the recipient view. Is there a configuration setting in DocuSign to hide the Documents Section (which contains the number of Documents in Envelope) displayed in right side of screen.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to hide the "Documents" section (displayed down the right side of the screen when viewing the Envelope) from the recipient. Amongst other things, this section can be a useful navigation aid for the signer, as the thumbnail images contain visual indicators of which pages require the signer's input, and the signer can also navigate to a specific page by clicking on the page's thumbnail image.